# Query to get 3rd largest amount and 2nd largest amount from table

Tags: sql

How to find 2nd and 3rd largest amount from a table

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT ... FROM ... ORDER BY column DESC LIMIT 2 OFFSET 1;
```

Depending on your SQL dialect there's a different way of specifying LIMIT and OFFSET.

Comment: This will not work in SQL 2005. But it is mainly used in MYSQL and PostgreSQL

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2000+

```
SELECT TOP 2
   *
FROM
   (
   SELECT TOP 3 * FROM table ORDER BY Something DESC
   ) T
ORDER BY Something
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2005+ you can use the [ROW_NUMBER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) construct.